# Not detecting javascript redirect from android webview click?

Tags: javascript, android, html, redirect

I would like to redirect to web page on android webview click,I have placed the below code in the javscript its not working.Kindly help me in solving this issue.Thank you.

```
function redirectCall(message) {        
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1)) {
    document.location = "http://www.google.com";
    } 
}
```